# How to rename a namedtuple argument in pycharm

Tags: pycharm, namedtuple

Config = namedtuple(
    'c', ['height']
)
DEFAULT_CONFIG = Config(height=4)

I want to rename the argument `height` to `start_height` everywhere in my code, including mentions of `config.height` and calls to `Config(height=4)`

When I click refactor on the string 'height' I get "cannot refactor".
When I click the `height` in the DEFAULT_CONFIG line, it doesn't find any other mentions. 
When I click code that uses `config.height` the rename option is greyed out.

Comment: It is not supported yet, please vote for https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-24122

Answer (score 0):

On mac, command-shift-r (or replace in path under Edit/Find) will allow you to click through every instance of the string `height` in the project and decide whether to replace that mention with `start_height`.